# Zip folder with password on node js(meteor/react)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, passwords, zip

So that's what I've got:
Client fills input form and send this data to the server. Server creates folder, where it generate JSON file with user data. In the same folder user uploads some files (images).

What do I need:
I need to zip this folder with password from the user sent input form. And send this protected zip file back to the client.

I've found library which make zip from the folder (like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-dir ) and the library which generates  single text file and makes password protected zip from it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/minizip-asm.js

Guys, I really need help ho to combine this two solutions)) Or maybe 
Maybe someone already had such an experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the solution:

```
var Minizip = require('minizip-asm.js');
var fs = require("fs");
var mz = new Minizip();


var image = fs.readFileSync('./1.jpg');

var text = new Buffer("Abc~~~");
mz.append("haha/abc.txt", text, {password: "123"});
mz.append("haha/abc2.jpg", image, {password: "123"});
fs.writeFileSync("abc.zip", new Buffer(mz.zip()));
```